# Debugging VBScript in Windows 10

Tags: debugging, vbscript, windows-10

I recently took the free Windows 10, upgraded it to Pro, and installed Office 2016 Home.  I seem to have lost all my debuggers.

I used to be able to type:

```
"%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe" "TestScript.vbs" //d //x
```

in Windows 7 and up would pop the debugger.  It all seems to have been removed -- even the debugger clsid is missing.

I don't want to install Visual Studio -- is there no way to get the minimalist debugger back?

Comment: Windows never shipped with a VBScript debugger. Microsoft once had a (very minimalistic) script debugger in the download area, but it has been removed long ago. If you still have the installer somewhere it might still work on Windows 10 (haven't tested, though). VBScript can also utilize the debugger from MS Office if that is installed, but perhaps the Home edition doesn't have it (or you didn't install it).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue after I'd installed MS Office 2010 on Windows 7 HB. [MS Script Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Editor) included in Office 2000 through 2007 only. So to make debug possible you still can install it from any of that packages. The example below is for Office 2003 installer on Windows 7:

Launch the installer, choose *custom type of installation*:

[image: custom type]

Uncheck all applications and check *choose advanced customization*:

[image: advanced customization]

Disable all components:

[image: disable all]

Go to *Office Tools - HTML Source editing - Web Scripting* and select *Run from My Computer* option for *Web Debugging* item:

[image: web debugging]

Then finish the rest installation process. After that you can debug the scripts with Script Editor debugger.

There is the same version of Script Editor in Office 2003 and 2007 installers that I checked:

[image: version]

I should say I havn't tested that on Windiws 10, seems Office 2003 is not certified compatible with Windows 10 but might work using compatibility mode, and Office 2007 have been confirmed to be compatible.

BTW, if you are using Notepad++, it may be handy to setup shortcut for launching the script with debugger. Enter `"C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript.exe" //x "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` into *The Program to Run* field while creating shortcut (you can find description [here](https://superuser.com/a/968513/367122)).

Comment: Worth noting that if you do this using Office 2007 then it'll take up 702MB of space, whereas using Office 2003 will "only" take up 370MB. In addition, you're forced to enter a valid CD key to progress with the Office 2007 installer, whereas you don't need to for Office 2003.