# How do I get a VBscript External tool that worked in Visual Studio 2012 but not in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vbscript

We are receiving an unexpected error when using our VBScript external debugging tool. We used this link in the past to create the external tool:
[Visual Studio 2013 and VB Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210905/visual-studio-2013-and-vb-scripts)

It has worked fine in VS2013 when we created the tool. Well, we moved to a new machine and now this tool will not work. We receive the following error asking us to register the PDM.dll or it is missing, which we have done. I'm assuming it is a configuration issue of some sort either in the Visual Studio 2013 or elsewhere. Would anyone have experience with this or could offer a suggestion?

Error:
"The script debugger failed to connect to the target process. The correct version of pdm.dll is not registered. ...."

I know this is common error but we have tried the common fixes that we are ware of.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried MS Script Editor instead of VS? Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38934476/2165759).

Comment: Visual Studio is the only tool we are allowed to use now.
Visual Studio 2013 worked fine with VBScripts after creating the tool under the Tools > External Tools. Now on my new desktop it doesn't.

Comment: When I loaded VS 2012 (with VS 2013 still installed), somehow it fixed the issue. Both 2012 and 2013 can debug VBScripts with use of the External Tool created for VBScript debugging.

We had this issue before in the past, on the previous machine (i.e. PC), it was just the opposite fix. VS 2012 wouldn't debug VBScripts with the External Tool created, but after loading VS 2013 it worked.

Somehow, the second installation changes the configuration which impacts both versions, resulting in the VBscript target connection to work. Anyone know why so I could mark an answer appropriately?

Comment: Even you don't know the root cause, IMO you can post the above comment as the answer yourself, since that fixed of the issue, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I loaded VS 2012 (with VS 2013 still installed), somehow it fixed the issue. Both 2012 and 2013 can debug VBScripts with use of the External Tool created for VBScript debugging. We had this issue before in the past, on the previous machine (i.e. PC), it was just the opposite fix. VS 2012 wouldn't debug VBScripts with the External Tool created, but after loading VS 2013 it worked. Somehow, the second installation changes the configuration which impacts both versions, resulting in the VBscript target connection to work.