# Can't debug Visual Basic Scripts

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, visual-studio-2017, xdebug, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug a VBScript. I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community edition, but whenever I run my script (with a `stop` placed near the beginning of the script), the Just-in-Time debugger does not pop up and my scripts continues.

I've looked at the following, and nothing has helped:

[Just-In-Time Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx)

- I've enabled it in Internet Properties.
- I've enabled "Managed", "Native", and "Script" in *Tools\Options\Debugging\Just-in-Time* in Visual Studio 2017.
- All the registry keys listed in the article are present in the registry.
- I was able to follow the article C# Console App example. It did (although with variable success) eventually get into the debugger.

[Visual Studio 2013 and VB Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210905/visual-studio-2013-and-vb-scripts)

- I tried debugging in the manner detailed here, but it never stopped at the `stop` or any of the breakpoints I set up.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the values in the registry are incorrect. The MSDN article didn't explicitly mention what the values should be.

Have other people tried using Visual Studio 2017 for debugging VBScripts? I've had luck using 2010 and 2012 at my work computer, but sadly I can't find downloads for those versions of Visual Studio for my home computer.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Try to launch the script with `//x` or `//d` command line parameter. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937673/2165759

Comment: Sadly, it's still behaving the same.

Comment: Also, I'm open to alternative programs/methods for debugging VBScripts. I just know that Visual Studio is one of the most common and generally most straightforward methods.

Comment: @MaxJacob I ended up buying a VBSedit licence which has built in debugging.

Comment: @NickPerkins Good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your VS as the admin, and enable the Script debugging under TOOLS->Options->JIT debugging, how about the result?

I used the VS2017 Enterprise version before:

[Visual Studio 2017 debugging vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226237/visual-studio-2017-debugging-vbscript)

Or check the workaround in this feedback which is similar to this issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30845/vs2017-script-jit-debugging-is-not-working.html